# Pack Convert byte array into UINT64

Tags: php, uint

I want to convert byte array to UINT64 using PHP.

I can do this easily in C# but I want to do this in PHP.

Here is C# code.

```
bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashed);
BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
```

I want to convert this to PHP.

I tried to use `pack()` function but this does not works.

Let's say this is a byte array.

```
$bytes = [101,102,54,55,99,55,56,49];
pack("J*","101","102","54","55","99","55","56","49");
```

This shows a warning.

> epack(): 7 arguments unused on line

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue here (if I understand it correctly) is you're using PHP numbers to represent a byte array however `unpack` requires an input string. If you keep the array as is then PHP seems to just convert the numbers to strings meaning a 101 will be '101' which in turn is 3 bytes, which breaks the whole thing down.

You need to first convert the numbers to bytes. A byte is essentially as an `unsigned char` so you could first pack your array into unsigned chars and then unpack them:

```php
$bytes = [101,102,54,55,99,55,56,49];
$unpacked = unpack("J", pack('C*', ...$bytes));

echo current($unpacked);
```

Explanation:

`C` is the pack code for unsigned char and `*` indicates that you need to use all array entries. This will generate a string of characters based on the array. You can then unpack this string using `J` (if you know for a fact that the bytes were generated in a big endian byte order) or `P` if you know the bytes were generated in little endian order or `Q` if you want to use the machine order. If the bytes were generated in the same machine then `Q` would probably be a better choice than `J` otherwise you need to know the endianess.

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cba2c29522f7b9f9a0748b99fac768012e759ce

Note: This is my personal understanding of what is happening so anyone with better pack/unpack knowledge can let me know if I got things wrong.